# Html won't load properly on the internet but is fine on dreamweaver

Tags: php, html, user-interface, web

I'm making a website with php and html using Adobe Dreamweaver and is hosted free by '000webhost.com'. So in one of my pages specifically my "inventory_list.php" page I have a table with input fields.

It looks like this on Dreamweaver:
[image]

But when I load it on the Internet it looks like this:
[image]

zoomed in:
[image]

It doesn't display the rest of the table, and the rest of the page.

Here is my inventory_list.php:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Inventory List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
<?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
<div id="pageContent"><br/>

  <div align = "right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="#inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New T-Shirt</a></div>
<div align="left"style="margin-left:24px">
  <h2>Inventory List</h2>
    <?php echo $product_list; ?>
    <p></p>
</div>
<a name="inventorForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
<h3>Add New Inventory Form</h3>


<form action="inventory_list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
<table width="646" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="131">Product Name &nbsp;</td>
      <td width="339"><label><input name="product_name" type="text" id="prdouct_name" size="60"/>&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Price &nbsp;</td>
      <td><label>Php&nbsp;<input name="productPrice" type="text" id="productPrice" size="20"/>&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Category &nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><select name="category" id="category">
          <option value=""></option>
                 <option value="NBA">NBA</option>
                 <option value="PBA">PBA</option>
                 </select></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td><label><select name="size" id="size">
          <option value=""></option>
                 <option value="small">S</option>
                 <option value="medium">M</option>
                 <option value="large">L</option>
                 </select></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Details&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><textarea name="productDetails" type="textarea" id="productDetails" cols="64" rows="5"/></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Image&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><input type="file" name = "fileField" id="fileField" />&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add this item now"/></label></td>
    </tr>
   
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>


<br />
<br />
<br />

  </div>

  
<div>
   

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't display after the textarea while it displays properly on dreamweaver. Sorry I have to put up something like this here but our progress presentation will be tomorrow and I need to continue on coding. All help is GREATLY APPRECIATED :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hadn't correctly closed the `<textarea>`. You had it self-closing (`<textarea />`) instead of `</textarea>`

Your amended code below, with a **[live fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kqcwwcam/)**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Inventory List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
<?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
<div id="pageContent"><br/>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
<?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
<div id="pageContent"><br/>

  <div align = "right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="#inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New T-Shirt</a></div>
<div align="left"style="margin-left:24px">
  <h2>Inventory List</h2>
    <?php echo $product_list; ?>
    <p></p>
</div>
<a name="inventorForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
<h3>Add New Inventory Form</h3>


<form action="inventory_list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
<table width="646" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="131">Product Name &nbsp;</td>
      <td width="339"><label><input name="product_name" type="text" id="prdouct_name" size="60"/>&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Price &nbsp;</td>
      <td><label>Php&nbsp;<input name="productPrice" type="text" id="productPrice" size="20"/>&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Category &nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><select name="category" id="category">
                 <option value=""></option>
                 <option value="NBA">NBA</option>
                 <option value="PBA">PBA</option>
                 </select></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td><label><select name="size" id="size">
                 <option value=""></option>
                 <option value="small">S</option>
                 <option value="medium">M</option>
                 <option value="large">L</option>
                 </select></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Details&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><textarea name="productDetails" type="textarea" id="productDetails" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Image&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><input type="file" name = "fileField" id="fileField" />&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add this item now"/></label></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</form>


<br />
<br />
<br />

  </div>


<div>


</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for taking this small problem here in stackoverflow. I'm not much into html and it's my first time coding php. Anyways a big thank you! :)